# bash, Traverse to same file to find the childs

Tags: bash, loops, awk, sed, associative-array

I have data in below format

```
1234|4568
4568|abcd
abcd|0987
pqrs|1111
0987|2222
lmno|xyza
```

expected output is

```
1234|2222
pqrs|1111
lmno|xyza
```

How it matches is for each record find its childs & subchild & take the lowest child entry with parent

say

```
a|b
b|c
c|d
```

so output needed for such entries is

```
a|d
```

also it may happen that

```
a|b
b|a
```

where `a|a` would be the output

I am gazling how can i get this?[Spent some hours thinking how to do this?]
can I use associative array in AWK?

Comment: ["All arrays in AWK are associative"](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one liner does what you want:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '{for(x in a)if(a[x]==$1){a[x]=$2;next}a[$1]=$2}
                       END{for(x in a)print x, a[x]}' file
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  cat f
1234|4568
4568|abcd
abcd|0987
pqrs|1111
0987|2222
lmno|xyza

kent$  awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '{for(x in a)if(a[x]==$1){a[x]=$2;next}a[$1]=$2}END{for(x in a)print x, a[x]}' f
lmno|xyza
pqrs|1111
1234|2222
```

Comment: I have generated a big file & tried both options. Your method is consumes more CPU & less Memory & Karakfa method consumes less CPU & more memory. Both Solves my cases. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not the complete solution but perhaps get you started...

```
$ awk -F"|" '{a[$1]=$2} 
          END{for(i in a) 
                {k=a[i]; 
                 printf i"/"k; 
                 while (k in a) {k=a[k]; printf "/"k}
                 print ""
                }
             }' file
abcd/0987/2222
4568/abcd/0987/2222
1234/4568/abcd/0987/2222
0987/2222
lmno/xyza
pqrs/1111
```

will give you the paths.  You need to eliminate the shorter sub-sequences and add cycle detection.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '1h;1!H;$!d;x;:a;s/\|([^\n]+)(.*)\n\1(\|[^\n]+)/\3\2/;ta' file
```

This slurps the file into memory and uses pattern matching and substitution iteratively until no further matches occur.